# Spark doesn't find BLAS in MKL dll

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea, blas, intel-mkl

I'm working on IntelliJ and specified this parameter to my JVM :

```
-Dcom.github.fommil.netlib.BLAS=mkl_rt.dll  (my mkl folder is in the Path)
```

However I still have the following warning :

```
WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: mkl_rt.dll
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this issue, here's the complete step to do make it work on intelliJ Idea on Windows :

First create an SBT project and make sure to put the following line in build.SBT :

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("com.github.fommil.netlib" % "all" % "1.1.1" pomOnly())
```

Refresh the project, after that you should have the libraries available. If that doesn't work for some reason, you can go here : http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/fommil/netlib/ and download the necessary resources for your system directly.

Copy your mkl_rt.dll twice and rename the copies libblas3.dll and liblapack3.dll. Make sure your folders containing all the Dll is in the PATH environment variable.

Finally, go to Run -> Edit configuration and in the VM options put :

```
-Dcom.github.fommil.netlib.BLAS=mkl_rt.dll
```